# substring SQL in bra

Tags: sql-server-2012, substring

I would like to separate a string in two columns. The string (s) could be in different lengh for example:

```
@string1 = (10)123514512(20)123412(30)123421523
@string2 = (10)12313123123123(30)351(21)324FE324F
```

These two lines as a result would be:

```
(column1) |s (column2) |ss
10        |s  123514512|ss
20        |s  123412   |ss
30        |s  123421523|ss
10        |s  12313123123123|ss
30        |s  351|ss
21        |s  324FE324F|ss
```

I tried to play a bit with the substring function but I have no Idea how to move forward. Any suggestion? thank you so much for your time and wisdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PATINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) is probably what you're looking for.  Since you have multiple instances of a pattern in each string, one approach is to use a while loop:
Find first instance of opening parenthesis, then find the first instance of a closing parenthesis, then use substring.  Set your pointer to the length of that substring.  Then repeat.

Usage:

```
select PATINDEX('%[(]%',colname) as indexOfOpen, PATINDEX('%[)]%',colname) as indexOfClose  from table
```

Take a look at this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41976

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it wasn't the full answer but you put me in the path. Greetings!